# How to highlight another menu with another active menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        $('ul.nav navbar-nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
           return this.href == url;
        }).parent().addClass('active');
    });
```

This is my code that highlight the current active menu but now i want to highlight another menu with other page.
for example if my page is /shops/add and i want to highlight the /shops/confirm menu.
what changes i need in my code?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/torifat/cake-menu_builder and a clean PHP approach that might make your JS code unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
if(url == "www.yoursite.com/shop/add"){
$('ul.nav navbar-nav a[href="www.yoursite.com/shop/add"]').parent().addClass('active');
}
    });
```

What I did was simply test the current page URL to the desired URL and selected the links with the `href` of the desired page and changed the class to "active".

Comment: ... and why should they?  Please provide some explanation.  The OP should understand how you created the code and the ramifications behind your choices so that they can ultimately decide whether or not this is suitable for their purposes.

Comment: all i dide is simply tested the current page url to the url i wanted and i selected the link with the href of the page i wanted change the the class to "active" and changed it

Comment: That's great.  Please place that in your answer as it may help other people who have similar problems as well.  Thanks!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      var url = window.location;
      
      $('ul.nav navbar-nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
      if(url == "muslimmaps.localhost.com/shops/register_shop_confirmation"){
         $('ul.nav navbar-nav a[href="muslimmaps.localhost.com/shops/register_shop]').parent().addClass('active');
       }
      $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
         return this.href == url;
      }).parent().addClass('active');
   });
   
</script>

Comment: **there is an error with your code :**
[href="muslimmaps.localhost.com/shops/register_shop]').
**should be**
[href="muslimmaps.localhost.com/shops/register_shop"]'). 
**note the " i added**

Comment: as far as i can see yes, but if you can you can put the code of the page here just to see if there is something we are missing

Comment: did you see my comments? i placed all the code in one of my comments

Comment: @Youness no more comments?

Comment: sorry man its al EID , kolo amin wa anta bikhayr , i will see into it now :)

Comment: Can we chat on any channel so that i can share my screen shot with.In this way you come to know what i want to do?